# How to get "file" parameter of http request in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to program a java script script that based on whether a user logs in properly or not will redirect them to a separate PHP script. The issue is that I can't seem to figure out how to get the file parameter of the request so that I can see if the request I'm looking for is there. How do I get the file parameter of a request in java script?
Sorry for misconceptions, what i mean by the file attribute is what is under the "file" section for each request in the following.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOHOg.png)

So if under the file tab of the packet, it set a certain file, how would i differentiate?

Comment: What you're asking doesn't make any sense.  Please try to clearly explain - HTTP requests do not have a "file parameter".

Comment: Well, HTTP requests *could* have a number of different things which could be called "a file parameter" but I've no idea which (if any) the OP is asking about. I don't even know which request they are asking about. The question needs a lot more information before it becomes answerable.

Answer (score -1):

It's not clear what you're asking. 
The part " so that I can see if the request I'm looking for is there" tells me, you want to debug your website, or at least, that's my interpretation of it.

If you use Chrome or [Firefox Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/), you can press F12 (or CTRL + SHIFT + J) to open the developer console.

Change to the tab "Network, and you'll see all the XMLHTTPRequests. 
Click on a specific request, and you'll see its details.

[image: Developer Tools]

A basic XmlHttpReuqest goes like this:

```
function reqListener () {
  console.log(this.responseText);
}

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
oReq.open("GET", "http://www.example.org/example.txt");
oReq.send();
```

And you get the result of your request in the callback function reqListener.

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

If you want to get the request handler's URL, that goes like this:

```
function reqListener (e) {
  //console.log(this.responseText);
   console.log(e);
   console.log(e.currentTarget.responseURL);

}

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
oReq.open("GET", "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58407228");
oReq.send();
```

And if you want to get a parameter called "file" inside an url, this goes like

```
function getUrlVars(urlHref)
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = urlHref.slice(urlHref.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(decodeURIComponent(hash[0]));
        vars[decodeURIComponent(hash[0])] = decodeURIComponent(hash[1]);
    } // Next i 

    return vars;
} // End Function getUrlVars


var dictParameters = getUrlVars("http://www.example.com/handler?file=bla.bin");

if (dictParameters.contains("file"))
{
    console.log(dictParameters["file"]);
}
```

As for XMLHTTPRequest, it doesn't have a property called file.

Also, this is 2019, you should be [using the FETCH-API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) with [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await), not the XMLHttpRequest-API, which doesn't use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

Here's a [getting started overview](https://javascript.info/async-await).

Edit:
Ah, I see:

If you have a url, such as

```
var url = "http://www6.scratch99.com/web-development/javascript/test.js?abc=def";
```

you do

```
var url = "http://www6.scratch99.com";
var urlParts = url.replace('http://','').replace('https://','').split(/[/?#]/);
var domain = urlParts[0];
```

to get the domain part. Then you subtract the domain (+protocol), and end it at ? or #:

Full code:

```
var url = "http://www6.scratch99.com/web-development/javascript/test.js?abc=def";
// var url = "http://www6.scratch99.com";
// var url = "http://www6.scratch99.com?test=123";
var protocol = url.substr(0, url.indexOf(":") + 3)

var urlParts = url.substr(protocol.length).split(/[/?#]/);
var domain = urlParts[0];

var fileParts = url.substr(protocol.length + domain.length);
var file = fileParts.split(/[?#]/)[0];
```

and if you want the filename only:

```
var pathParts = file.split('/');
var fileOnly = pathParts[pathParts.length-1];
```

Comment: The question is asking how to do something (which *might* be this, it really isn't clear) in JavaScript … not by using the developer tools GUI.

Comment: @Quentin: It's not clear what he's asking. The part " so that I can see if the request I'm looking for is there" tells me, he wants to debug his website, or at least, that's my interpretation of it.

Comment: It says "in javascript" twice and in the tags. That seems pretty clear. The rest, doesn't seem clear at all. I don't think the question is answerable in its current state.

Comment: @Quentin: Agree with you there.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. Hopefully the edits help?

Comment: @PMD: Still not very clear. Are you trying to redirect a user based on the current url ? Or are you trying to determine if a loggin succeeded or not ? Or are you trying to see what happens, all the request and response files transmitted ? That you'd better do with fiddler:  https://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: I'm trying to determine whether a login succeeded or not.  Im determining based on the packets they respond with.